# Изменение стандартных параметров на WiX.com

Tags: javascript, site

Добавил WIX Forum на сайт, как на этом конструкторе изменять поля и элементы которые не имеют привычных настроек для этого сайта, может можно как то переопределять параметры через WIX Corvid? Но пока ничего не могу найти.

На скриншоте видно что всплывающее окно очень большое по отношению к меню справа, нужно как то то окно уменьшить.

[image: Как?]